# MVC Grid - does the FooterTemplate aggregation work when the source is via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, footer, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm working on a customer's MVC application, where they have a fully-functional Telerik MVC Grid control, which makes an Ajax call as the datasource.  They have asked me to add a total to three of the columns, below each column.  FooterTemplate is the obvious choice for this.  However, the data always comes back as null.

In searching the web, I notice that the only samples using FooterTemplate have the datasource passed into the constructor; no example uses both FooterTemplate (with aggregates) and Ajax databinding.  Is there a way to do this?

I appreciate any help.

-Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Check the [ajax aggregates](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregatesajax) example.